# Django AJAX increment

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am simply trying to create a button or link in Django that when clicked will increment a model.IntegerField, but so far have been awfully confused. I understand that I must AJAX-ify this process. I tried using [Dajaxice](http://dajaxproject.com)

but ended up running into many troubles.

What is the accepted way to do this? Thanks!

So far I'm just following Dajaxice's tutorial.

My base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML Transitional//EN"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}

My Blog
        {% dajaxice_js_import %}

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function my_js_callback(data){
            if(data==Dajaxice.EXCEPTION){
                alert('Error! Something happens!');
            } else {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><a href=””>My Blog</a></h1>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

Within that block content I have `<a href="" onclick="Dajaxice.example.myexample(my_js_callback);">Click me!</a>`

this code `{% dajaxice_js_import %}` generates `<script src="/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>` which is just `http://localhost:8000/dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js`

So far the problem is that that file can not be found, and yet I have placed it under /templates/dajaxice/

Not sure what to do. Thanks!

**Edit after mention of static files**

So it looks like I am not placing my static files correctly. I followed the instructions at[Django's docs how to serve static files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/)

Let me know if I did this right. I have created a folder "static" under "myProject/static". I have placed my JS files within static/ For example "myProject/static/prototype.js"

I also have `STATIC_URL='static'`
and `'django.contrib.staticfiles',` in INSTALLED_APPS

I now try to grab prototype.js using `<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}prototype.js"/>`but still no avail...

What am I doing wrong now?
Thank you!
**Edit:**looks like /static/ should be inside the app folder. How confusing...

Comment: Can you give an example of problems you run into and/or the code you are using?

Comment: Edited my question with sample code. I am not using jQuery or any other AJAX libraries. Dajaxice is supposedly built such that we do not need any AJAX libraries.

Comment: This appears to be a static files issue, nothing to do with AJAX at all. Static files belong in the static or media directories, not under templates.

Comment: I have edited my question. Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to do it atomicly:

```
# models.py
class Page(models.Model):
    hits = models.PositiveIntegerField()

# views.py
def hit(request, page_pk):
    Page.objects.filter(pk=page_pk).update(hits=F('hits')+1)
    return HttpResponse()
```

…or use a transaction:

```
# views.py
from django.db.decorators import commit_on_success

@commit_on_success
def hit(request, page_pk):
    page = Page.objects.filter(pk=page_pk)
    page.hits += 1
    page.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where is the transaction?

Comment: Thanks! Then how do I make a button or a link call hit()?

Comment: Add a URL pattern for the view, then use ajax to request the URL.